# Xamarin Form, change activity when navigated to another page?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

It is a little bit confusing to understand the relation between the navigation of the shared module and the activities in Android project.

I put the MainPage inside a `NavigationPage` so that the Android toolbar would appear. I added a help menu to the toolbar. When the menu is clicked, I called `Navigation.PushAsync(new HelpPage())` in the shared module. It looks as if a new activity is started for the help menu. The toolbar shows a back arrow, and I can go back with the back button.

In native Android, this would mean a new activity. But I only have one activity in the Android project. Should I create a new activity like "HelpActivity"? Then, how can I switch to the HelpAcitvity, when navigated to the HelpPage as in the previous paragraph?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you push a new HelpPage, that means you already implemented a new page in the shared environment. What do you need a new activity for?

Comment: I am new to Xamarin, and in Microsoft's tutorial videos, the speakers touted how everything is automatically translated into the native platform things. That kind of thing (tapping the help menu) starts a new activity in native Android, so I thought I needed to assign a new activity for the help page. But it turned out (according to the answer), Xamarin fakes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Xamarin Forms uses only a single fragment and you should not try and work around this. Pages get loaded and unloaded from this.

[Here are more details and a discussion around it](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65395/does-xamarin-forms-always-use-a-single-android-activity)

Comment: Yeah, when looked closely, it seems the page change behaviour is a fake. I mean, it looks as if a new activity starts, but I can notice weird residues and delays (when the back button is pressed, the toolbar title remains that of the help page for a split second and then changes to that of the main page).